# Which Desktop Environments do not require D-Bus?

Tags: desktop-environment, d-bus

Are there Desktop Environments (i.e. something comparable to Gnome, KDE, Xfce etc.) which do not require D-Bus?

An optimal answer would best give a comprising list or alternatively confirm that today Desktop Environments necessarily depend on D-Bus (possibly giving a reason why this is so?)

Comment: I don't think you will find any DE's, but there are at least a few standalone window managers.

Comment: Given that there are so many ways for communicating unix-sockets, pipe, shared files etc... I was and am still hopeful somebody can find somehting. Or maybe there is a good reason why D-Bus should always be the best solution?

Comment: Having not programmed directly with d-bus, I can't much about it, but probably the reason is *portability.*  D-bus provides a cross platform abstraction layer for IPC.  Pipes, sockets, shmem, etc. don't.  And the big DE's all strive to be cross-platform.

Comment: The *portability* seems to be at the expence to more effort in configuration. Thanks to stuff exposed via D-Bus there can be plenty of additional attack vectors, or else a heavy configuration effort has to be done to keep up safety. As obvisiouly the D-Bus way is ignorant of the file permissions. Stuff not available via filesystem might be accessible via D-Bus. There must be people who dislike this and hence favour a no D-Bus DE, right?\

Comment: @humanityANDpeace D-Bus permissions work just like user process permissions, IIRC. e.g. an unpriveleged process cannot connect to the system bus (the D-Bus daemon running as root).

Comment: @strugee to quote a comment line in an dbus config file(bluetooth.conf on a Ubuntu 12.04LTS) `<!-- ../system.conf have denied everything, so we just punch some holes -->` it seems they work quite somewhat distinct. At least permissions do not try to poke whole put to avoid them. also permission are done via `chmod` mostly. With D-Bus I am XML file editing. A D-Bus less DE hence would reduce the workload. I could only focus on file permissions and restrict processes via LSM.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace Adding layers of abstraction is more likely to introduce vulnerabilities than eliminate them, sure, and whatever additional configuration that layer requires is additional (although it may abstract away others).  WRT "people who dislike this", they're called "stand alone window manager" users in this case, lol.  DE's are mostly chintz, bells, and whistles anyway.  With the exception of some time when GNOME first appeared, I did not normally use one until last year, when I switched to KDE from fvwm2...

Comment: ...and TBH, since I still use the same common set of tools otherwise, the difference is pretty superficial.  Just be warned that if you don't like having to configure things yourself, you probably won't enjoy stand-alone WM land.  Everything involves trade-offs.  If I was really concerned with security in a big way, would I use a DE?  No.  Too much opaque stuff that is largely irrelevant to me.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace yes, I didn't say that filesystem and D-Bus access controls work in the same way. I'm just saying that D-Bus access controls _do_ work.